# Not getting desired outputs from loop conditions

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a nested dataframe:

```
df1:
name   date    amount
A     2019      10
B     2019      20
C     2019      30
d     2020      10
e     2020      20

df2:
name   date    amount
f      2019      5
g      2019      10
h      2020      10
i      2020      10
j      2020      5
k      2020      5
```

And I am currently looping through it and trying to print statements adding the amount of 'amount' by the year and the percentage difference based on if it decreased or increased.  DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Df1: DECREASED -  pre_count: 60  now count: 30 difference: -50%
Df2: INCREASED -  pre count: 15  now count: 30 difference: 100%
```

This is what I have:

```
def percentage():
    amountlist = []
    pre_count = 0
    now_count = 0
    pre_date = 2019
    now_date = 2020

    for name, df in dfnest_dict.items():
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['date'] == pre_date:
                pre_count += row['amount']
            elif row['date'] == new_update:
                new_count += row['amount']

    x = pre_amount_count
    y = now_amount_count

    math = int(((x - y)*100) / y)

    if(y>x):
        msgone =  str("{}: INCREASED PRE COUNT: {} NOW COUNT {} DIFFERENCE {}%".format(name, x, y, math))
        amountlist.append(msgone)
        inc_str = str("\n".join(amountlist))
        return devicelist, inc_str
    elif(y < x):
        mstwo =  str("{}: DECREASED PRE COUNT: {} NOW COUNT {} DIFFERENCE {}%".format(name, x, y, math))
        amountlist.append(mstwo)
        dec_str = str("\n".join(amountlist))
        return devicelist, dec_str
```

When I call the function with:

```
one, two = percentage()
```

and print them I only get one output and sometimes its the wrong message. I'll get the decreasing message instead of increasing etc

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following is a simple solution for the given scenario:

```
def percentage():

  df1_2020_sum = df1.loc[df1['date'] == '2020', 'amount'].sum()
  df1_2019_sum = df1.loc[df1['date'] == '2019', 'amount'].sum()

  df2_2020_sum = df2.loc[df2['date'] == '2020', 'amount'].sum()
  df2_2019_sum = df2.loc[df2['date'] == '2019', 'amount'].sum()

  if (df1_2020_sum - df1_2019_sum ) < 0 :
      df1_result = 'DECREASED '
  else:
     df1_result = 'INCREASED '

  if (df2_2020_sum - df2_2019_sum ) < 0 :
      df2_result = 'DECREASED '
  else:
     df2_result = 'INCREASED '


  df1_difference = ((df1_2020_sum - df1_2019_sum)/df1_2019_sum)*100
  df2_difference = ((df2_2020_sum - df2_2019_sum)/df2_2019_sum)*100


  print("df1: {} PRE COUNT: {} NoW COUNT {} DIFFERENCE {}%".format(df1_result,df1_2019_sum, df1_2020_sum, df1_difference))
  print("df2: {} PRE COUNT: {} NoW COUNT {} DIFFERENCE {}%".format(df1_result,df2_2019_sum, df2_2020_sum, df2_difference))


percentage()
```

You will get your desired output as follows:

```
df1: DECREASED  PRE COUNT: 60 NoW COUNT 30 DIFFERENCE -50.0%
df2: DECREASED  PRE COUNT: 15 NoW COUNT 30 DIFFERENCE 100.0%
```

Comment: The only problem is that I want to keep my loops just in case I add more dataframes

Comment: @JTHDR Just a suggestion:  if you are so sure that your all dataframes are going to have same columns then I will suggest you should concatenate all the dataframes in two sub dataframes using pandas function pd.concat() and use the above solution. Because using nested for-loop in the code is not a good idea if you have other efficient solutions.